400 error on calling Google Apps Script from Wordpress
I created and exposed this very simple Google Apps Script:
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log('Data received : ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({status: 'error', message: error.message})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Only POST request accepted.");

With these settings:
Execute as me and everyone can access.
But when I try to call it from wordpress it fails with 400 error.
I can see the call in the executions historic from GAS editor but with no logs at all.
Here is the result of this curl command:
curl -L -X POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxxb17haq53hMcRnfPIwIz9vNamPar4qXYKEmToq2gOTpw9iHRIrc7DnTXgg7c45PS3/exec \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"email": "test@example.com", "progression": 50, "id_formation": "formation123"}'


Page introuvable.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{margin:18px 0;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap}.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png);-webkit-background-size:116px 41px;background-size:116px 41px;display:inline-block;height:41px;vertical-align:bottom;width:116px}.docs-drivelogo-text{color:#000;display:inline-block;opacity:.54;text-decoration:none;font-family:"Product Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:32px;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;position:relative;top:-6px;left:-7px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:144dpi){.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png)}}sentinel{}body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;} DriveImpossible d'ouvrir le fichier pour le moment. Vérifiez l'adresse, puis réessayez.Efficacité maximale avec Google DriveLes applications Google Drive simplifient la création, le stockage et le partage en ligne de documents, feuilles de calcul, présentations et bien plus encore.Pour plus d'informations, consultez la page drive.google.com/start/apps.html {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}body {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}#outerContainer {margin: auto; max-width: 750px;}#innerContainer {margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 80px; position: relative;}%   

In the meantime I made more investigation.
I found a way to write logs in a Google Sheet file and here is what I found :
Here is the data sent by postman with success:
{
    "contentLength": 0,
    "parameters":
    {
        "email":
        [
            "john_doe@fakemail.com"
        ],
        "progression":
        [
            "50"
        ],
        "id_formation":
        [
            "5"
        ]
    },
    "contextPath": "",
    "parameter":
    {
        "email": "john_doe@fakemail.com",
        "progression": "50",
        "id_formation": "5"
    },
    "queryString": "email=john_doe@fakemail.com&progression=50&id_formation=5"
}

And here is the data sent by Thrive Auto with 400 error and something that looks odd to me but I'm not an expert (see this part : {"postData":{"contents":"{"":""}","length":7,"name":"postData","type":"application/json"}):
{
    "postData":
    {
        "contents": "{\"\":\"\"}",
        "length": 7,
        "name": "postData",
        "type": "application/json"
    },
    "contextPath": "",
    "parameters":
    {
        "progression":
        [
            "50"
        ],
        "email":
        [
            "john_doe@fakemail.com"
        ],
        "id_formation":
        [
            "5"
        ]
    },
    "parameter":
    {
        "email": "john_doe@fakemail.com",
        "id_formation": "5",
        "progression": "50"
    },
    "contentLength": 7,
    "queryString": "email=john_doe@fakemail.com&progression=50&id_formation=5"
}

Regards,
Florent

In your showing curl command and With these settings: Execute as me and everyone can access., please modify as follows and test it again.
Modified curl command:
curl -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxxb17haq53hMcRnfPIwIz9vNamPar4qXYKEmToq2gOTpw9iHRIrc7DnTXgg7c45PS3/exec \
-d '{"email": "test@example.com", "progression": 50, "id_formation": "formation123"}'

About I can see the call in the executions historic from GAS editor but with no logs at all., in this case, this information might be useful. Ref (Author: me)
Note:

I guessed that in your showing curl command, the Google Apps Script works. But, the correct response is not returned. In this case, this post might be useful. Ref (Author: me)

References:

Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)
Web Apps
Understanding Flow of Request to Web Apps Created by Google Apps Script (Author: me)


Thank you Tanaike!
You're right, the "curl -L " is working (so in GET type I suppose, not POST).
In the meantime I successfully made a POST call with postman.
And successfully wrote log in a GSheet file to see what's was sent. I saw your article but I don't remember where to find the access token.
So I compared data sent by Wordpress (Thrive Automator) and data sent by postman. I contacted Thrive Automator to get help.

I'm surprised that this documentation explain nothing about how to structure the request data to avoid 400 error.
And why it's made so complicated with redirections as you explains there.

@Florent Thank you for replying. About the access token, in the case of With these settings: Execute as me and everyone can access., the access token is not required to be used. So, I didn't use it in my modified curl command. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replies, I couldn't understand what result you obtained when you tested my modified curl command. Can I ask you about it? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue with my proposed answer. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

I really appreciate your help and don't worry for your english ;-)
I was speaking about the token to get logs in the GAS dashboard. I understood reading your article that it was needed for that. Right? In the meantime I found a way to get logs in a GSheet file so I added to my question more details about differences between data sent by postman and data sent by Thrive Automator (wordpress). What do you think about that?

@Florent Thank you for replying. I was surprised that you updated your question. In your initial question, you wanted to modify your curl command. But, in your updated question, do you want to modify your postman? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. I would like to propose to resolve your question in order. Can I ask you whether your initial question was resolved? And, can I ask you about the details of the issue of my answer to your initial quesiton?

Hi @Tanaike, I used curl and postman just to check that my GAS was ok but my goal is to call my GAS webhook from wordpress's Thrive Automator plugin without a 400 error as response from Google.

@Florent Thank you for replying. About I used curl and postman just to check that my GAS was ok but my goal is to call my GAS webhook from wordpress's Thrive Automator plugin without a 400 error as response from Google., in your initial question, you wanted to remove the error from your curl command. My answer resolves this error. About your actual goal, I would like to propose to post it as a new question. Because your actual goal is different from your initial question. If you can cooperate to resolve your actual goal, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

@Florent By the way, when you post it as a new question, please post it by including more information. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. And, when you post it as a new question, please close this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers If you can cooperate to resolve your actual goal, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Hi @Tanaike, I hope your are fine. I'm sorry but I think my initial goal was quite clear in the initial title "400 error on calling Google Apps Script from Wordpress" and the first lines of my initial description too "...when I try to call it from wordpress it fails with 400 error". Are you sure I should create another question (the title should be the same).

@Florent Thank you for replying. At your initial question, the returned value from the curl command was shown and you wanted to resolve this issue. The request is used with the curl command. In your actual goal, it seems that you are not using the curl command. So, I proposed posting your actual goal as a new question by including more information. When you post a new question, please include more information. By this, it will help users think of a solution.

Ok @Tanaike I created this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79117544 and closed the actual question.

@Florent Thank you for replying. I will check your new question. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.
